# Questions re Time Series Forecasting in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima, vector-autoregression

I am attempting to build a time series model that can predict order volumes for a single firm in the trucking industry.

I have time series data on the firm's order volumes. I expect also to have access to time series data on say 5 macroeconomic variables that I believe are in some way correlated with the order volumes I am seeking to predict. I would prefer to work in R.

My questions are:

1. Am I correct to say that I should be building a VAR (Vector Autoregression) model of some kind?  Or should I be looking at a multi-variable ARIMA model?
2. Would I be on the right track to use the MTS package in R?  Alternatively, would the MARSS or marima packages be a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Am I correct to say that I should be building a VAR (Vector Autoregression) model of some kind? Or should I be looking at a multi-variable ARIMA model?:

There is no need for a VAR model as your  macro-economic predictors are most-likely not dependent on your Y variable.

Yes you should be looking at a multi-variable ARIMA model called correctly as a Transfer Function OR sometimes called a Dynamic Regression OR more frequently called a SARMAX model.  https://autobox.com/pdfs/SARMAX.pdf

If you post your data in a csv file , I might be able to help further.

You might also look at [Create auto regressive regressors in R (extract from auto.arima)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/451011/create-auto-regressive-regressors-in-r-extract-from-auto-arima/451013#451013) and it's references.